# Get status of connection pool in npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I use npgsql 3.2.6 in .net core 2. Is it possible to get status details of connection pool to see how many connection there are and how many of them are free.
for example npgsql max pool size is 100 and there are 100 connection in it. when query postgresql can see there are 100 idle connection but how can we find how many of these 100 connection are free to use?

Comment: If they are in the pool, they are ready to use. What are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to know connection in use of the pool. Because when query in postgres to get connections count it shows number of all connection in the pool but i want to know how many of them are used at a time in my application and how many of them are free